# What are the theorems behind this variance formula?

Tags: variance

I saw below formula to derive the variance calculation for $Var(\widehat{\delta_{cdx+}})$. I am wondering what theory has been applied in the second and third rows.
[image]

Comment: The transformation from the first to the second line follows the law of total variance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance.

Comment: ... and the calculations in the last line rely on the defining properties of variances (bilinearity), expectations (linearity), and conditional expectations, of which the most important is sometimes called ["pulling out known factors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).